# Click on row in table to get info from child element

Tags: javascript

I have a table generated with data from an array (the array contains more info than what is displayed in the table). I want to click on a row to see all info from the element.

Earlier done it like this:

```
let rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

 for (let row of rows) {
        row.onclick = function rowClicked(evt) {
        selected = myArray[evt.target.parentElement.rowIndex];
        //code (not relevant)
        }
```

But since I added a search feature `myArray[1]` is not necessarily equal to row number 1 and this method doesn't work.

Is it another way to find the element in the array from clicking on a random row?

The table is generated like this:

```
function drawTable(data) {
    let table = document.getElementById("table");
    table.innerHTML = "";

    let tableHead = document.createElement("thead");
    let colHeads = ["Names"];

    for (let header of colHeads) {
        let cell = document.createElement("th")
        cell.innerHTML = header;
        tableHead.appendChild(cell);
    }
    table.appendChild(tableHead)

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

        let row = document.createElement("tr");

        let name = document.createElement("td");
        name.innerHTML = data[i].name.first + "&nbsp" + data[i].name.last;
        row.appendChild(name);

        table.appendChild(row);
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the HTML of the `<table>`, at least a sample row `<tr>` element. Without your question is not a [example] as required to solve. If there were any _index_ or _key_ inside the `<tr>` we can use to lookup the element in the array, it would be easy.

Comment: You did not show the code for "table generated with data from an array" - is it like in [your recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70786516/generate-new-table-when-searching)? Inside this implementation you can __link the array-index to the DOM-element__ (i.e. the `<tr>`), e.g. via an _attribute_ like `id` or `data-index`. See MDN: [Using data attributes - Learn web development](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: Sorry my fault. I have a `searchbar`, and whenever you type something inside the table gets deleted and a new one is created (in the new table only the results containing the string in `searchbar` is displayed). `ID` or `data-index` is a nice idea, but is it possible to "lock" the id to a row in the first table (where all names is displayed) and use them in the new table?

Answer (score 1):

You need some way to map a table row to its relevant entry in `myArray` which isn't dependent on the position of the row in the table.  Data attributes wouldn't be affected.

Create a `data-index` attribute on each table row.  Then, when it's clicked use the value of the `data-index` attribute to access the relevant `myArray` entry.

Comment: @hc_dev Yep, that's what I meant.  Thanks for catching that.  Updated.

Comment: Found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224866/how-to-get-table-row-by-using-id-in-html), which was solved with ubiquitous `id` attribute populated from array to store the index.

Answer (score 0):

A simple version of what you have in mind. The visible line is bound with a click event. As soon as it is triggered, it gets the ref-id from the clicked element and toggles the reference column.

```js
const clickables = document.querySelectorAll('.clickable');
console.log(clickables)

clickables.forEach(tr => {
  tr.addEventListener('click', (e) => {    
    const ref = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-ref');
    const row = document.querySelector('#' + ref);
    row.classList.toggle('hide');    
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.clickable:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr class="clickable" data-ref="a">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="a" class="hide">
    <td>a1</td>
    <td>b2</td>
  </tr>  
  
  <tr class="clickable" data-ref="b">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="b" class="hide">
    <td>a3</td>
    <td>a4</td>
  </tr>    
</table>
```